# Comparing Text Isn't Working in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, swt

So, I'm trying to do something really simple, and that's check if a password equals something in my SWT application. So, my code was this:

```
if (passwordBox.getText() == "test") {
    passwordBox.setVisible(false);
}
```

However, in my application, which uses text fields marked as passwords (with that variable), it **will not** fire that when I click a button. I already have button handling working, since I have an `else` statement that fires, but this will not fire when the password box obviously equals "test". What's wrong here?

Comment: Don't use "==" to compare strings. Instead use the `equals(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are always compared by `equals()`.

```
if(("test").equals(passwordBox.getText())) {
   passwordBox.setVisible(false);
}
```